# generating words in R

Tags: r

for simulation purposes, I'm trying to figure out how to generate a long finite string of text of English letters with spaces and periods.  I've been playing with concatenate and reg. exp, and looking at help files, but being a newbie to R, not making much progress.  All I got so far is `x <- sample(c("a", "b", "c", " ", ".", 100, replace=TRUE)`.  Well, that's only three letters.  i've been trying [a:z] and things like that, but c() doesn't seem to like that and gives errors.

Then, even if I enumerate every single letter in c(), the sample function returns a character vector with each letter being an element:

```
str(x)
chr [1:100] "c" "b" "a" "b" ...
```

but I need the whole string to be just one element in a character vector.  An example of a function I'm looking for would generate a text string like "asdf twdjk.fd alw" of any length I want, in this case 17. So if I do a str() on the result, it should give me:

```
str(x)
chr "asdf twdjk.fd alw"
```

Thank you in advance for any tips.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do this? Are there any other constraints? You might get better answers if you provide that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R provides all the letters in the alphabet as a built-in constant, so to get the characters to generate from, you can just do:

```
chars = c(letters, " ", ".")
```

Then use `paste0` to combine the results of your sampling into a single string:

```
paste0(sample(chars, 100, replace=TRUE), collapse="")
```

Comment: Awesome!  Much appreciated, Marius.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone can do better:

```
Alphabet <- c(LETTERS, " ", ".")

set.seed(123)
x <- sample(Alphabet, 17) # maybe replace=TRUE
x <- as.list(x)

pasteNoSpaces <- function(...) paste(..., sep="")  # paste0 is better
do.call("pasteNoSpaces", x)
```

Comment: Marius's answer is better.